# How to Store a NumericField of type SHORT in Lucene

Tags: java, solr, lucene, elasticsearch

I'm working with Lucene 3.5.0 
I have developed a CustomScoreQuery using a FieldScoreQuery on a type FLOAT and it works just fine.

I don't actually need the precision of a float, what I have are numbers between -1 and 1 and I would be fine with a 0.001 precision, so I just need to represent 2000 values. I would like to use a FieldScoreQuery of type SHORT. From the javadoc of FieldScoreQuery.Type

```
    BYTE consumes 1 * maxDocs bytes.
    SHORT consumes 2 * maxDocs bytes.
    INT consumes 4 * maxDocs bytes.
    FLOAT consumes 8 * maxDocs bytes.
```

So I tried:

```
new FieldScoreQuery(FIELD_MY_RANK, FieldScoreQuery.Type.SHORT));
```

if I make FIELD_MY_RANK a NumericField of type integer, it breaks at query time.

```
NumericField rankFieldShort = new NumericField(
FIELD_RANK,
Field.Store.NO,
true).setIntValue( to_short(myRank) );
```

It works fine if I use FieldScoreQuery.Type.INT   but in this case I'm still using 4 bytes instead of 2.

I also tried to use a byte field, using 2 bytes to represent my Short int. In this case I always get 0 back from the index in the CustomScoreQuery.

```
Field rankFieldShortBytes = new Field(
RANK, to_bytes(myRank) );
```

So the question is, **what kind of Field do I need to create to be able to use a FieldScoreQuery.Type.SHORT** ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems Lucene cannot deserialize short values from field FIELD_MY_RANK when it was added as NumericField. Try following code:

```
Field rankFieldShort = new Field(FIELD_MY_RANK, Short.toString((short) myRank), Field.Store.NO, Field.Index.ANALYZED_NO_NORMS);
```